# angular render model one by one

Tags: angularjs, view, render

Suppose I have a JSON with a list of cars:

```
{
  "company": "Mercedes",
  "cars": 
  [{
    "idCar": 1,
    "Name": car 1,
    "img":"..."
  },{
    "idCar": 2,
    "Name": car 2,
    "img":"..."
  },{
    "idCar": 3,
    "Name": car 3,
    "img":"..."
  },{
    "idCar": 4,
    "Name": car 4,
    "img":"..."
  },{
    "idCar": 5,
    "Name": car 5,
    "img":"..."
  }]
}
```

I’m doing an Angular application where a user can push a button to show these cars, but the user should only see one car at a time, when he’s finished seeing the specs for this car, he can click a **"next"** button and the next car should be displayed and so on and so forth.

Now as you might notice I'm a beginner at Angular and I would like to know if there is a way of doing that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your JSON seems wrong. Name field value should be in quotes if it's String

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a pretty basic Angular question. This should get you in the right direction:

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

    $scope.company = {
        company: "Mercedes",
        cars: [
            { "idCar": 1, "Name": "car 1", "img": "http://lorempixel.com/200/200" },
            { "idCar": 2, "Name": "car 2", "img": "http://lorempixel.com/200/200" },
            { "idCar": 3, "Name": "car 3", "img": "http://lorempixel.com/200/200" },
            { "idCar": 4, "Name": "car 4", "img": "http://lorempixel.com/200/200" },
            { "idCar": 5, "Name": "car 5", "img": "http://lorempixel.com/200/200" }
        ]
    };

    $scope.currentIndex = 0;
    $scope.currentCar = $scope.company.cars[$scope.currentIndex];

    $scope.nextCar = function() {
        $scope.currentIndex++;

        if ($scope.currentIndex >= $scope.company.cars.length) {
            $scope.currentIndex = 0;   
        }

        $scope.currentCar = $scope.company.cars[$scope.currentIndex];
    }
}]);
```

view:

```
<div>
    <h1>{{ currentCar.Name }}</h1>
    <img ng-src="{{ currentCar.img }}" />
</div>
<button ng-click="nextCar()">Next</button>
```

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3ay4hkj/4/)

Comment: In addition for a pretty and easy way to do it. You could use a carousel https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, this will help a lot.